# Catching unhandled request in Kohana 3

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I have done this simple catch:

```
try
{
    echo Request::factory()
        ->execute()
        ->send_headers()
        ->body();
}catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo 'You tried to reach: ?';
}
```

in the bottom of my bootstrap.php and removed

echo Request::factory()
    ->execute()
    ->send_headers()
    ->body();

From the root index.php. This works fine, and the output "You tried to reach ?" appears when there's a request of something unhandled.

I wish to mention the URI in this output message.

My further plans are to check in the DB for URI that matches the unhandled request, so for now I need to grab the URI you have tried to access.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `Request::detect_uri()`

Documentation: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Request#detect_uri

Comment: I tried echo Request::factory()->uri(); , outputted a '1', and url() outputted '/index.php/1' which is not the url i tried to access

Comment: Yes, sorry. Try "detect_uri". Do not use "factory".